# Cat contents of each file in directory into csv record

Tags: bash, shell

I need to prepare a csv as a means to load data. I have a directory which holds n number of html files. The code of each of html file needs to be copy and pasted into a csv field. Ideally this is what I would like the csv to look like

```
FileName                     Code
filename1.html               contents of filename1.html here
filename2.html               contents of filename2.html here
```

I know there is way to pipe the ls of the directory into a csv, however I am not sure on how to achieve the following result.
I am thinking that I probably need create a loop and have the file appended each time with delimiter added at each interval. But I am not quite sure where to start. Writing this as a shell/bash script would be best

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: putting an entire html file contents **into** a csv doesn't sound like a good idea to me, this will be hard to escape with all the quotes

Comment: The html file is actually pretty small, its just a e-signature with probably like 5 lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

- create a folder with the files `a` and `b` that I have mentioned above
- create a file called `shell.sh` with the contents of the script inside this folder

Run the following command to make your shell script executable

```
chmod +x shell.sh
```

Before running the script, change the line from:

```
files=$(ls)
```

to

```
files=$(ls | grep -v shell | grep -v csv)
```

Then run the following command to see the output of the script

```
./shell.sh
```

Now redirect it to your csv file:

```
./shell > file.csv
```

To see the content of the file `file.csv` run:

```
cat file.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

Say you have two files:

file `a` contains:

```
abc

123
```

file `b` contains:

```
def

456
```

so:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Filename,Code"

files=$(ls)

for file in ${files[@]}; do
    echo -n $file,
    tr -d '\n' < $file
    echo ""
done
```

The above code will output:

```
Filename,Code

a,abc123

b,def456
```

Comment: Thanks. How would i move this to a csv I tried using > test.csv when calling the script but I received errors on execution

Comment: what erros did you get?

Comment: I see what the problem is, there are commas in the code that is causing the output to split before the actual file ends

Answer (score 0):

Not bash, but simple ruby script to make a CSV file with filename and file content as columns:

```
require 'csv'

@path = ARGV[0]

files = []
files << ['filename', 'contents']
Dir.foreach(@path) do |filename|
  next if filename == '.' or filename == '..'

  files << [filename, File.read("#{@path}/#{filename}")]
end
File.write("#{@path}/result.csv", files.map(&:to_csv).join)
```

Usage: `ruby script.rb <path>`